# How too add extra params in redirect when an instance variable is passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
#in update function
redirect_to @post
```

Here I want to add some additional params when redirecting. However, as I try to add

```
redirect_to @post, :mypara => 'abc'
```

the page redirected to does not have this parameter in address bar, so I tried to print is out using

```
<%= params[:mypara] %>
```

but still nothing could be seen.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `post_path` like this:

```
redirect_to post_path(@post, :mypara => 'abc')
```

This:

```
redirect_to @post
```

actually translates to:

```
redirect_to post_path(@post)
```

If you want to pass extra parameters, you cannot use the short cut. You have to use `post_path`.